# How to rename a database from psql in metabase

Tags: metabase

We have a metabase server that is linked to a psql server. When we perform qa testing or development testing we rename its database name from prod to qa or dev.

For other applications we just alter the name of the database via psql, but it does not have  [Database name:] among the parameters in table

Is it possible to set the new database-name over psql? 
[metabase screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sh82M.png)

```
select * from metabase_database;
```

-[ RECORD 1 ]---------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

```
id                          | 2
created_at                  | 2019-05-19 08:25:49.063+00
updated_at                  | 2019-05-19 08:25:49.177+00
name                        | PROD
description                 |
details                     | **********************************
engine                      | postgres
is_sample                   | f
is_full_sync                | t
points_of_interest          |
caveats                     |
metadata_sync_schedule      | 0 50 * * * ? *
cache_field_values_schedule | 0 50 0 * * ? *
timezone                    | UTC
is_on_demand                | f
options                     |
```

Comment: Do you have credential encryption turned on?